# Exclude column while reading the file pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Im wondering how can I read the `parquet` file and create a `df` but would like to exclude one column. Rather selecting 20 column I prefer to exclude one column. Note: this should happen while `spark.read`.

Comment: probably you can use simple .drop on dataframe, it should be pushed down to reader and this column should be skipped

Comment: how will it be the syntax? i just tried somehting like this `df2 = (spark.read.format('parquet').drop('_SysRowId') .schema(schema)
           .load()
      )`

Comment: drop is from df api so it can be used after load

Comment: xxx.load().drop("column_name")